# Proving that a set and operation form a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> $S$ is a nonempty finite set with associative operation $∗$ such that, $$∀ a, b ∈ S, ∃ c,d ∈ S\text{ s.t. }a ∗ c = b \text{ and }d ∗ a = b$$Prove that $(S, ∗)$ is a group.

I'm stuck on a difficult problem from some PSET I found online (I'm self studying Algebra).

I have been trying to show the existence of an identity in $S$ on $*$ as I think the rest will follow, but I cannot seem to make any progress.

My work so far is not very solid, but it is an attempt to show that there is at least one $e$ exists such that

$$a ∗ e = e ∗ a = b, \text{ where }a,b\in S$$

Reasoning as follows:

From the problem statement:

$$∀ (a, b) ∈ S × S\ ∃ (c, d) ∈ S × S:\ a*c = d*a = b$$

I would like to show that at least one such $(a, b)$ has $c = d$.

I try a proof by contradiction:

Assume

$$∀ (a, b) ∈ S × S\ \exists (c, d) ∈ S × S\ c ≠ d:\ a*c = d*a = b$$

Since $S$ is finite, so let $|S| = n$.

$$\therefore|S × S| = n^2$$

But there are $n(n-1)$ pairs of the form $(c, d) ∈ S × S$ such that $c ≠ d$.

From here I am trying to use the pigeonhole principle to show that there exists $(a,x)$ and $(b,y)$ such that

$$(a = b\text{ and }x ≠ y)\text{ or }(x = y\text{ and }a ≠ b)$$
that satisfy

$$a*c = c*a = x$$

$$b*c = c*b = y$$

leading to an obvious contradiction.

I think there is a way to derive this existence, since intuitively there are $n$ "excess" pairs after relating pairs $(a, b)$ one-to-one with pairs $(c, d)$.

I would greatly appreciate a hint.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your work and we will be happy to help :-)

Comment: @Aatmaj sorry, I didn't add it as I find it a bit weak, but it is the best I have managed thus far.

Comment: @JamesMullen in order to find an identity element, you should find an $e \in S$ such that $ae = ea =a $ for every $a \in S$ and not $ ae = ea = b$.

Comment: @P.J. That is the objective, but ae = ea = b would be a good start

Answer (score 1):

The conditions can be restated that left and right multiplication by every element of your set is bijective. So, $x\to a x$ is a permutation $\pi_a$ of your set. Since every permutation has finite order, $\pi_a^k = \pi_{a^k}$ is the identity permutation for some $k,$ and that shows that $a^k$ is the (left) identity element. Similarly $a^l$ is the right identity, so your set has a left and right identity. A standard argument shows that these are the same. Since left and right multiplications are bijective, it shows that you have a left and a right inverse for every element (and and another standard argument shows that *those* are the same.)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I wrote a proof far simpler than what I was trying to do above. Might be helpful to someone at some point so:
From the problem statement:

*Existence of right and left identities for each element*
∀  ∈, ∃ *e*, *e*' ∈:
*ae = a* and *e'a = a*

*Right and left identities are universal*
Now:
∀ *b* ∈ , ∃ *x*, *y* ∈:
*ax = b* and *ya = b*
⇒ *e'ax = e'b* and *yae = be*
⇒ *ax = b = e'b* and *ya = b = be*
In other words, *e* is a left identity for all elements of S, and *e'* is a right identity for all elements of S.

*Equivalence of right and left identities*
∃ *q* ∈:
*qe = e'* ⇔ *q = e'*
*e'e = e'*
Similarly, ∃ *p* ∈:
*e'p = e* ⇔ *p = e*
*e'e = e*
so:
*e = e'*

*Uniqueness of the identity*
We have shown that if a left-inverse for one element is a left-inverse for all elements, and that such a left-inverse is also a right inverse. Now suppose ∃ *p* ∈:
*al = la = a* for some *a* ∈
It follows that:
*el = e*
But *el = l*, since e is an identity for all elements
So *l = e*.

*Existance of inverses*
For any element *a* ∈,  ∃ *a<sub>r</sub><sup>-1</sup>, a<sub>l</sub><sup>-1</sup>* ∈ :
*aa<sub>r</sub><sup>-1</sup> = e*
*a<sub>l</sub><sup>-1</sup>a = e*
⇒ *a<sub>l</sub><sup>-1</sup>(aa<sub>r</sub><sup>-1</sup>) = a<sub>l</sub><sup>-1</sup>*
⇒ *a<sub>r</sub><sup>-1</sup> = a<sub>l</sub><sup>-1</sup>*
So for all *a* ∈ , we have *a<sup>-1</sup>* ∈

*Uniqueness of inverses*
Suppose *ab = e*
⇒ *a<sup>-1</sup>(ab) = a<sup>-1</sup>e*
⇒ *b = a<sup>-1</sup>*
So each element has a unique inverse.

*Closure*
let *xy = z*
⇒ *x = zy<sup>-1</sup>*
From the problem statement, we know there exists *p* in S:
*x = py<sup>-1</sup>*
⇒ *xy = p*
⇒ *z = p*

Hence *{S, ∗}* is a group

Please feel free to suggest edits, and do let me know if I made a mistake.